# How to run function before first render in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have a context in my App.js file that stores the current user's data like this and configures everything in case they had already signed in

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ user, setUser }), [user, setUser]);
  const cookies = new Cookies();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = cookies.get("token");
    //If the user had previously signed in retrieve its data
    if (token !== undefined) {
      fetch(`auth/users/${token}`).then(res => res.json()).then(user => setUser(user));
    }
  }, []);
```

And then I have a function in my mods page that wouldn't allow you to access it unless you're a moderator. Mainly for if the person tries to access it by directly typing the URL.

```
    const history = useHistory();
    const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user.role !== "moderator") {
            createNotification("You are not a moderator", "error");
            history.push("/admin-login");
        }
    }, [])
```

If I understand correctly, *UseEffects* get triggered from children to parent. So if I go directly to *website.com/mods* (code above) and have previously logged in, it will first check for the user's role (it hasn't yet been set so it will always be true and redirect me) and then go to App.js and setup the user there.

Is there any way to revert this effect so that no matter what the first thing that will happen when the website is accessed is the user being set up?

Update: Here's what userContext looks like

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext(null);

export default UserContext;
```

Comment: This would be a lot clearer if you provided the definition and usage for `UserContext`. Personally, I'd make the getters for things like `role` async

Comment: @Phil `UserContext` is just a variable that stores `createContext()` and async calling might work but I still have the issue of the variable being checked before it is set

Comment: That's what I mean by making it async. Change `role` to a function (`getRole`) that returns a promise that only resolves once the value is confirmed

Comment: @Phil But how would I make it a function? user.role is just a context variable, is there a way to store functions in context?

Comment: This is why I asked for the definition of your context. And yes, you can put anything you like in context

Comment: @Phil Updated the question with the definition

Comment: What sort of values are you setting into the context? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Phil An object that looks like `{username, role, token}`